# Should we keep the [front-panel] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

While questions tagged with [front-panel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/front-panel) seem to be really about it, is this tag useful for anything?

Comment: -1 for not having a creative title

Comment: My immediate thought for "front panel" was something like: [Altair Computer Front Panel](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Altair_Computer_Front_Panel.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the tag [port](https://superuser.com/tags/port/info) refers to network ports, not hardware ports.

[case](https://superuser.com/tags/case/info) does seem to offer questions regarding computer cases.

[motherboard](https://superuser.com/tags/motherboard/info) is frankly, unwieldy in searching for this information.

Searching for [motherboard+port](https://superuser.com/search?q=motherboard+port) isn't specific in trying to find questions about the front panel.

Searching [motherboard+front](https://superuser.com/search?q=motherboard+port) gets us a bit closer to what we want and [motherboard+front+port](https://superuser.com/search?q=motherboard+front+port) is about as close as we're going to get without "front panel".

Searching [motherboard+front+panel](https://superuser.com/search?q=motherboard+front+panel) will get us what we want. There are [74](https://superuser.com/search?q=motherboard+front+panel+is%3Aquestion) of those questions with only [11](https://superuser.com/search?q=motherboard+front+panel+is%3Aquestion+%5Bfront-panel%5D) having the front-panel tag.

There are [26](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/front-panel) questions *total* tagged with the front-panel tag.

---

To me, the front-panel **phrase** is necessary, but I'm unsure about the actual tag. No doubt it would just get recreated, though. Seems like maybe a better option would be to sort out questions that have to do with the front panel ports and get them into the tag?